# Line is not displaying where lat and long define

Tags: qgis, linestring

I have created 3 lines by importing them into QGIS 3 with the Add Layer/ Delimiter Text option and it does display on the map (I have added an OSM layer to understand where the line is located) but the line is supposed to be close to Las Vegas, NV (long: -114.7092, lat: 36.2565) but it is off the coast of Africa - see image below. The extents are:

Extent
-116.0046389999999974,36.7258830000000032 : -115.9775159999999943,36.7416350000000023

I am using the WGS 84 Pseudo-Mercator project for both the lines and the OSM map.

Here is the text file I import:

oid;Line
TOPIC;LINESTRING(-115.977516 36.725883, -115.977516 36.741635)
YES;LINESTRING(-115.977516 36.741635, -116.004639 36.741635)
NO;LINESTRING(-115.977516 36.741635, -115.977516 36.741635)

[image]

Comment: Your data is in geographic degrees. You should use WGS84 EPSG:4326, not Pseudo-Mercator. By selecting EPSG:3857 you are telling QGIS that your data is roughly 116 meters west and 37 meters north of the origin (intersection of equator and prime meridian).

Comment: @BenW this is the answer, why have you added it as a comment?

Comment: @Spacedman - I assume BenW didn't answer because this is a duplicate of about 100 other "I don't understand projections" questions that the OP won't bother to read

Comment: @BenW That would explain it! I made the change and tried it and sure enough that was the problem! Thanks you so much!! Is there a way to give you credit for the answer?